# MenuMatic selected menu item dissapears when selected Update

Tags: css, mootools

So when I select the menu item from my drop down list, it disappears when it loads the link.  I have verified that the menu items are set to display on all pages. Is this a css setting ? 
Thanks

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img13/8528/7nu6.png]
[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img850/6708/8mn7.png]

CODE: added per request

```
/*
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Templates for Joomla 2.5 / Joomla 3.x
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (C) 2011-2013 Jtemplate.ru. All Rights Reserved.
# @license - PHP files are GNU/GPL V2.
# Author: Makeev Vladimir
# Websites:  http://www.jtemplate.ru/en 
# ---------  http://code.google.com/p/jtemplate/   
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/* all menu links */
#nav a, #subMenusContainer a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    background-color:#fff ;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

/* Just main menu links --[for non-javascript users this applies to submenu links as well]*/
#nav a{
    margin:0;
    float:left; 
}

/* Just sub menu links */
#subMenusContainer a, #nav li li a{
    text-align:left;
}

/* All menu links on hover or focus */
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus, #subMenusContainer a:hover, #subMenusContainer a:focus, #nav a.mainMenuParentBtnFocused, #subMenusContainer a.subMenuParentBtnFocused{
    background-color:#3366FF ;
    color:#FFF;
}

/* sub menu links on hover or focus */
#subMenusContainer a:hover, 
#subMenusContainer a:focus, 
#nav a.mainMenuParentBtnFocused, 
#subMenusContainer a.subMenuParentBtnFocused,
#nav li a:hover,
#nav li a:focus{
    background-color:#3366FF ;
    color:#FFF;
}

/* Parent Sub Menu Links ---[javascript users only]*/
.subMenuParentBtn{ 
    background: url(../images/arrow_right.gif) right center no-repeat;  
}

/* Parent Sub Menu Links on hover or focus ---[javascript users only]*/
.subMenuParentBtnFocused{ 
    background: url(../images/arrow_right_over.gif) right center no-repeat;  
}

/* Parent Main Menu Links ---[javascript users only]*/
.mainMenuParentBtn{ 
     background: url(../images/arrow_down.gif) right center no-repeat; 
}

/* Parent Main Menu Links on hover or focus ---[javascript users only]*/
.mainMenuParentBtnFocused{  
    background: url(../images/arrow_down_over.gif) right center no-repeat; 
}

/* ----[ OLs ULs, LIs, and DIVs ]----*/

/* Submenu Outer Wrapper - each submenu is inside a div with this class - javascript users only */
.smOW{ 
    display:none; 
    position: absolute; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    /*the 2px left & right padding lets you have a 1px border 
      on the ul or ol inside since overflow is set to hidden*/
    padding:0 2px;
    margin:0 0 0 -2px;
}


/* All ULs and OLs */
#nav, #nav ul, #nav ol, #subMenusContainer ul, #subMenusContainer ol { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1em;
}

/* All submenu OLs and ULs */
#nav ol, #nav ul, #subMenusContainer ul, #subMenusContainer ol {    
    /*border around submenu goes here*/  
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    background:#fff;    
    border:1px solid #3366FF;
    left:0;
}


/* List items in main menu --[for non-javascript users this applies to submenus as well]  */
#nav li { 
    /*great place to use a background image as a divider*/
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

#subMenusContainer li{
    list-style: none;
}

/* main menu ul or ol elment */
#nav{
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    z-index:5;
/*  top:15px;*/
/*  left:50%;*/
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
}

#subMenusContainer{ display:block;  position:absolute;  top:0;  left:0; width:100%; height:0;   overflow:visible;   z-index:1000000000; }


/* --------------------------[ The below is just for non-javscript users ]--------------------------*/
#nav li li{ float:none; }

#nav li li a{ /* Just submenu links*/   
    position:relative;
    float:none;
}

#nav li ul { /* second-level lists */
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    margin-left: -1000em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isn't read by screen readers */
    margin-top:2.2em;
}

/* third-and-above-level lists */
#nav li ul ul { margin: -1em 0 0 -1000em; }
#nav li:hover ul ul {   margin-left: -1000em; }

 /* lists nested under hovered list items */
#nav li:hover ul{   margin-left: 0; }
#nav li li:hover ul {   margin-left: 10em; margin-top:-2.5em;}

/* extra positioning rules for limited noscript keyboard accessibility */
#nav li a:focus + ul {  margin-left: 0; margin-top:2.2em; }
#nav li li a:focus + ul { left:0; margin-left: 1010em; margin-top:-2.2em;}
#nav li li a:focus {left:0;  margin-left:1000em; width:10em;  margin-top:0;}
#nav li li li a:focus {left:0; margin-left: 2010em; width: 10em;  margin-top:-1em;}
#nav li:hover a:focus{ margin-left: 0; }
#nav li li:hover a:focus + ul { margin-left: 10em; }
```

Thanks, updated comments

Comment: probably the color of the active link is set to #fff

Comment: If you provide actual code you have better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Seems like the "active link" is not defined on the css. Sergio you are correct in the code you pointed out. That's where it changes the text to white with the blue background when hovered over.  I wonder where the "active link" css is defined. Thanks

Comment: You should see it in the console. Do you have a live link?

Answer (score 0):

It can be here:

```
/* All menu links on hover or focus */
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus, #subMenusContainer a:hover, #subMenusContainer a:focus, #nav a.mainMenuParentBtnFocused, #subMenusContainer a.subMenuParentBtnFocused{
    background-color:#3366FF ;
    color:#FFF;  /* Try #AAF here  */
}

/* sub menu links on hover or focus */
#subMenusContainer a:hover, 
#subMenusContainer a:focus, 
#nav a.mainMenuParentBtnFocused, 
#subMenusContainer a.subMenuParentBtnFocused,
#nav li a:hover,
#nav li a:focus{
    background-color:#3366FF ;
    color:#FFF; /* Try #AAF here  */
}
```

This CSS makes the color of the text white. THe background here is in not white but after in the CSS you have `background:#fff;` applied to `#nav ul`.

If this doesn't work you need to post your html, make a fiddle or post a live link.